# Plant species ID, Bangladesh

Tags: botany, species-identification

[image]

[image]

[image]

This plant is quite common in vegetations near swamp areas in Bangladesh. I have included multiple picture hope that compensate for the bad quality.

Comment: Any chance you could give a close-up of the flower?

Comment: Probably Salvia genus: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salvia but that's just a guess, I never learned botany.

Comment: These pictures are terrible. The best I can tell is that the plant has inconsistently perfoliate leaves. this might help with the ID

Comment: I'm from West Bengal and don't know this plant. Since this plant is common to your locality, please upload photos of far better quality. You could take help of any friends's camera if your camera is troublesome, and could take photograph under bright sunlight, that will shorten the exposure time, so less haze. Please provide enlarged image of the inflorescence and flowers. You could give image of interior/ dissection of flower.

Comment: maybe this plant grow well in salty condition like Sundarban mangroves.